# Test if python3 is installed in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

How can I get something like this working ?

```
PYTHON3_OK = $(shell python3 --version 2> /dev/null | wc -l)
ifeq ($(PYTHON3_OK), 0)
    $(error package 'python3' not found)
```

The error is always show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting the number of output lines is an antipattern anyway. How about

```
PYTHON3_OK := $(shell python3 --version 2>&1)
ifeq ('$(PYTHON3_OK)','')
    $(error package 'python3' not found)
endif
```

or of course the more standard

```
PYTHON3_OK := $(shell type -P python3)
ifeq ('$(PYTHON3_OK)','')
    $(error package 'python3' not found)
endif
```